# Is the "homework" tag suitable for non-homework questions?

Tags: discussion

I just discovered there is the [homework](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag that *" lets potential answerers know that they should guide the student in solving the problem, rather than simply showing the complete answer."*

But is there another tag for people that are not strictly speaking *students looking for help with their homework*, but that nevertheless requires extra guidance? I think for example in enthusiasts, hobbyists or people new to the DSP field but that needs help with a particular project (the latter being my personal case)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to flag this is as [<kbd>self-study</kbd>](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-study).

It has similar connotations to homework, but we'll probably do more than guide the self-studier compared with the homework requester.

Comment: Thanks, @Peter. I completely missed that tag :/ The tag didn't have any description yet, so I took the liberty of editing it accordingly to your answer: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info Since I do not have the necessary privileges, it should be currently in the review queue.

Comment: Cool! Edit approved. :-) Welcome!